# How to findUnique on a relation field in Prisma?

Tags: javascript, sql, postgresql, prisma

I'm using Prisma with Postgres and I have a schema something like

```
model User {
  id                  Int                  @id @default(autoincrement())
  uuid                String               @unique @default(uuid())
  house House?
}

model House {
  id            Int      @id @default(autoincrement())
  user          User     @relation(fields: [userId], references: [id])
  userId        Int      @unique
}
```

Each house will have a unique user associated with it. I'd like to find the one house that is associated with a unique user i.e.

```
prisma.house.findUnique({
  where: {
    user: {
      uuid: <given userId>
    }
  }
})
```

But this doesn't work because the user field on House is not `@unique` and if I try adding `@unique`, prisma says relation fields can't be unique.

So how do I accomplish finding a unique house given a unique user when relation fields can't be unique? Is there a better way to query this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can change the query other way around and get the house details

```js
prisma.user.findUnique({
  where: {
      uuid: <given userId>
  },
  include: {
    user: true
 }
})
```

This should provide you with House details.

If you want to query on house model, you would need to enable [extendedWhereUnique](https://www.prisma.io/docs/reference/api-reference/prisma-client-reference#filter-on-non-unique-fields-with-userwhereuniqueinput) preview feature and make sure to pass atleast one unique attribute in the where clause.